# Lookup value with in range and return to first row cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match, lookup

I have data in range B2:D6 , I need to search any value within  this range and equation give corresponding cell in column A, if i search for H The result is 23 , also columnA may have duplicate, but search range have no duplicate .

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use AGGREGATE:

```
=INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($B$2:$D$6)/($B$2:$D$6=H2),1))
```